# If $s_{n}$ converges why does $\sqrt{s_{n}}$ converge only when $s_{n}$ is positive.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

So I've been trying to figure out if it's true that if $s_{n}$ converges $\sqrt{s_{n}}$ converges. I've found proofs on here that this is true if $s_{n}>0$, but I can't find out why it isn't true if there are negative numbers. Why does the introduction of imaginary numbers break this rule? Can someone explain it, or provide me with an example of a series where $s_{n}$ converges and $\sqrt{s_{n}}$ doesn't.

Edit: I think it may have to do with the fact that the complex numbers aren't an ordered field, but I'm still not sure how to formalize this.

Comment: Most probably in a context where complex are not allowed.

Comment: probably the result you found is only for reals and in which square root of negative numbers are not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that $\sqrt{s_n}$ is ambiguous if $s_n<0$. *Which* square root do you have in mind?

But that's not the only problem. Take the sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ defined by $s_n=-1$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$, let $t_n=(-1)^ni$. Then, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $t_n$ is a square root of $s_n$. However, $(s_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, whereas $(t_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ doesn't.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: The second part is not that much of a problem, right? As the original sequence converges, we can pick a branch of the square root that makes the statement correct.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Sure we can.